# Java: Releasing a lock only for a specific method

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, locking

Suppose I have 3 methods: A, B and C, which all need to be accessed in a synchronized manner (I will use Java Reentrant Lock for the example, but I am looking for any way to solve this problem).  One of these methods (say, A) will need to release the lock while it waits for another (B) to obtain the lock so it can update some state.  However, when A releases the lock, I only want it to be "claimable" by B, not C or any other routine.

```
Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
Condition cond = lock.newCondition();
boolean satisfied = false;

methodA() {
    lock.lock();
    // ...
    while(!satisfied) {
        // releases lock, waits for methodB to update state        
        cond.await();
    }
    // ...
    L.unlock();
}

methodB() {
    L.lock();
    // updates state, and notifies 
    satisfied = true;
    condition.signalAll();
    L.unlock();
}

methodC() {
    // Don't want C to be able to claim lock while A is doing await()
    L.lock();
    // ...
    L.unlock();
}
```

In other words, methodA gives privileged access to methodB.  After hunting for awhile I'm not able to find any obvious solution, but I imagine this being solved by some sort of locking level mechanism, ie:

```
methodA() {
    lock.privilegedLock();
    // ...
    L.unlock(); // exits privileged state if it is last privileged lock
}

methodB() {
    L.privilegedLock();
    // ...
    L.unlock(); // exits privileged state if it is last privileged lock
}

methodC() {
    // Don't want C to be able to claim lock while
    // it is in "privileged" lock state.
    L.normalLock();
    // ...
    L.unlock();
}
```

The main constraint is that all operations need to be synchronized using the same lock, otherwise I run into deadlock problems due to locking order, as these methods are spread throughout multiple classes which interact bidirectionally with one another.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you thought about a second condition that C could await and A will signal when done?

Comment: Sounds like you have some very tight coupling between your threads.  Can you say more about the problem that you are trying to solve?  Maybe there is a better way.

Comment: I think there is a better way, and that is probably what I'll end up doing instead.  I was just curious if the type of locking described above can be done.  Perhaps there was some handy class or idiom I could learn.